# jQuery - lock scrollbar and prevent page from jumping to the top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I want to lock the scrollbar on window when the overlay is triggered which is working fine. But the problem is the body/ document jumps to the top when you scroll the page to the bottom/ middle and trigger the overlay.

I don't want the page to jump to the top. What I want to achieve is **similar to Facebook's image overlay/ popup** when you click on the image - it locks the background when you click on the image but it stays as it s when you exit the image popup. Is it possible?

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000;
}

html.lock-scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#main {
    height: 2000px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.overlay {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

jQuery:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    console.log(windowHeight);

    $("#main").click(function(){
        $("html").addClass('lock-scrollbar');
        $('.overlay').show();
        return false;
    });

    $(".overlay").click(function(){
        $("html").removeClass('lock-scrollbar');
        $('.overlay').hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="main">
    <h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies sed mattis sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>

    <p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor cursus. Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

What have I done incorrectly?

My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t65y2xvw/).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would lock the scroll in this way instead of using a `fixed` positioned `lock-scrollbar`:

```
$('html,body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
```

on the click of `main` and `overflow-y` back to `auto`:

```
$('html,body').css({'overflow-y': 'auto'});
```

when the `overlay` is hidden.

See demo below and [**`updated fiddle here`**](https://jsfiddle.net/6ny6xaad/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  // console.log(windowHeight);

  $("#main").click(function() {
    $('html,body').css({'overflow-y': 'hidden'});
    $('.overlay').show();
    return false;
  });

  $(".overlay").click(function() {
    $('html,body').css({'overflow-y': 'auto'});
    $('.overlay').hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  color: #000;
}
html.lock-scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.overlay {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla
    commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies sed mattis
    sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend
    pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor cursus.
    Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to stick with the `position: fixed` solution - get / Set the value of `scrollTop` to reset the scroll.

Also added in `$('html').css({'top':-scrollTop + 'px'})` while locking scroll - see demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  // console.log(windowHeight);
  var scrollTop = 0;

  $("#main").click(function() {
    scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    $("html").addClass('lock-scrollbar');
    $('html').css({'top':-scrollTop + 'px'});
    $('.overlay').show();
    return false;
  });

  $(".overlay").click(function() {
    $("html").removeClass('lock-scrollbar');
    $(window).scrollTop(scrollTop);
    $('.overlay').hide();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
}
html.lock-scrollbar {
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  height: 2000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.overlay {
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  overflow: auto;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="main">
  <h1>New Scrolling Window</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam a justo erat, volutpat hendrerit dolor. Sed urna nibh, dapibus at egestas non, vulputate ut quam. Morbi a erat tristique tellus varius venenatis. Aenean lacinia sem eget turpis fringilla
    commodo. Sed lorem nisi, viverra a interdum nec, varius eu enim. Donec ornare, nunc quis eleifend iaculis, nulla eros mollis tellus, quis faucibus risus odio non lectus. Maecenas ac velit non metus rhoncus commodo. Nunc ligula est, ultricies sed mattis
    sed, dapibus at arcu. Maecenas lacinia nisl ut sem bibendum ac condimentum purus facilisis. Curabitur ut nibh lobortis libero interdum vehicula vel quis nulla.</p>

  <p>Suspendisse et massa urna. Donec eu lorem nec felis dapibus aliquam viverra in quam. Suspendisse ultrices, nisi ac venenatis porttitor, erat turpis dapibus augue, sed rutrum nunc ante sed enim. Aliquam et tempus mi. Nullam malesuada, nunc a eleifend
    pretium, justo lorem tempus justo, id adipiscing dolor ipsum sed velit. Maecenas odio massa, feugiat vel sodales ut, placerat at quam. Cras viverra diam vitae diam elementum vitae aliquet erat tincidunt. Quisque fringilla neque in lacus tempor cursus.
    Curabitur eget nulla et nisi dignissim tempor vel non risus. Mauris ac ipsum metus, a auctor massa. Nunc eros ante, ullamcorper a mollis nec, aliquam sed est. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Comment: thanks but you have changed what I am actually after.

Comment: @teelou check out the edit above and let me know, thanks!

Comment: it seems with the hack but i'm still looking for better solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Try CSS:

```
html, body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #000;
}
```

Try JS:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  console.log(windowHeight);

  $("#main").click(function(){
    $('body').css({
      overflow: 'hidden',
      height: '100%'
            });
    $('.overlay').show();
    return false;
  });

  $(".overlay").click(function(){
    $('body').css({
      overflow: 'auto',
      height: 'auto'
            });
    $('.overlay').hide();
    return false;
  });

});
```

Your modified jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y9e1kt3q/

New fiddle (the scroll remains visible): https://jsfiddle.net/y9e1kt3q/1/

Comment: thanks but you are doing the same as what I did - the page jumps to the top.

Comment: Only on Chrome it seems. Just a sec.